# Start a FlutterActivity subclass using a cached engine

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I'm currently adding a view developed using Flutter to an existing Android app. I have been following the tutorials found in the Flutter [website](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/add-flutter-screen) and decided to used a cached engine in order to minimize the delay that users may experience when navigating to the Flutter portion of the app. In order to do so, you must launch your Flutter activity like

```
startActivity(
    FlutterActivity
      .withCachedEngine("my_engine_id")
      .build(this) // this is a Context
```

)

After a while I need to wirte a method channel to communicate from the Flutter portion of the app back to the Android host app, so I followed the instructions found in another of Flutter's [tutorials](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=android-channel-kotlin-tab), where it is shown that the activity that implements the channel must extend `FlutterActivity`.

So my problem is that I'm not sure how to initialize this activity using a cached engine, since I obviously can't use `FlutterActivity.withCachedEngine` anymore. Has anyone solved this already?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After looking at `FlutterActivity` documentation I found the `provideFlutterEngine` [method](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/embedding/android/FlutterActivity.html#provideFlutterEngine-android.content.Context-). The doc description clearly states that:

> This hook is where a cached FlutterEngine should be provided, if a cached FlutterEngine is desired.

So the final implementation of my class looks like this now

```
class MyActivity : FlutterActivity() {

    override fun provideFlutterEngine(context: Context): FlutterEngine? =
        FlutterEngineCache.getInstance().get(FlutterConstants.ENGINE_ID)

    override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, "my-channel")
            .setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
                if (call.method == "my-method") {
                    myMethod()
                    result.success(null)
                } else {
                    result.notImplemented()
                }
            }
    }

    private fun myMethod() {
        // Do native stuff
    }

}
```

And I simply start it writing `startActivity(Intent(this, MyActivity::class.java))`

Comment: Hello, how it working in xcode? I need your help!

Comment: If  you've followed the Flutter tutorial you need to update the Android manifest to include your Flutter activity instead of the FlutterActivity from the tutorial. You also need to put a FlutterEngine into the cache at some appropriate place so your Flutter activity can get the cached version of the engine.